# Replace NSUrlConnection with NSUrlSession

Tags: nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

Hi I have a project using NSurlConnection I just want to replace it with NSUrlSession .Following is the code .KIndly help with the changes.

```
- (IBAction)getResponse:(id)sender
{
    [status setText:@"Retrieving response async"];
    [response setText:@""];

    NSURL *requestUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:url.text];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:60.0];
    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connection start];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *) connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSLog(@"Response recieved");
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*) connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    NSLog(@"Data recieved");
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [response setText:responseString];
    [status setText:@"Response retrieved async"];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   [[[NSURLSession sharedSession]dataTaskWithRequest:request 
  completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * 
  _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable connectionError) {
   //Handle your response
   }] resume];
```